# Under which conditions can dllhost.exe spawn child process? | MITRE ATT&CK T1191

Tags: incident-response, threat-mitigation, attack-vector, apt, incident-analysis

I was looking for conditions/circumstances under which Dllhost.exe can spawn a child process. I examined a huge quantity of event logs from various Windows system and didn't come across any event in which Dllhost.exe spawns a child process.

The only noticeable event(eventid:4688) was dllhost.exe --> cmd.exe which was a result of a simulated 'cmstp UAC Bypass' attack.

Scenario:

- Threat hunting for [MITRE ATT&CK T1191](https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1191/).
- Initial IOC being dllhost.exe spawning child process(attacker
  payload/elevated shell).

I am planning not to look for specific dllhost.exe-->cmd.exe events as they limit the scope of rule.

***The insight I am looking for is: If we create a detection rule for T1191 which triggers when dllhost.exe spawns a child process what is going to be the success rate and how many false positives could arise from this particular rule.***

PS: Looking for events where cmstp.exe is spawned and examining the commandline for certain execution flags might seem like a better approach but that will not tell us about the final elevated program that has been launched.

Answer (score 0):

> PS: Looking for events where cmstp.exe is spawned and examining the
>   commandline for certain execution flags might seem like a better
>   approach but that will not tell us about the final elevated program
>   that has been launched.

It depends on the data/visibility you have. If you have visibility to see a process's parent's command line, then one way to detect the behavior is to alert on any process whose parent has the GUID(s) associated with UAC bypass.

As far as the question of how often does dllhost.exe spawn a child process - it is fairly common. So - if you do not have visibility into parent command lines - perhaps the scope could be narrowed to command interpreters, scripting engines, and executables from "non-standard" paths, all whose parent is dllhost.exe.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use Sysmon or an EDR. Native Windows Security Logs alone won't help.
Examining the commandline would also be helpful on rule creation and lessens the rate of false positives since it is a specific procedure/technique.

---

Sysmon events can also be used to identify potential abuses of CMSTP.exe. Detection strategy may depend on the specific adversary procedure, but potential rules include:

1. To detect loading and execution of local/remote payloads - Event 1 (Process creation) where ParentImage contains CMSTP.exe and/or Event 3 (Network connection) where Image contains CMSTP.exe and DestinationIP is external.
2. To detect Bypass User Account Control via an auto-elevated COM interface - Event 10 (ProcessAccess) where CallTrace contains CMLUA.dll and/or Event 12 or 13 (RegistryEvent) where TargetObject contains CMMGR32.exe. Also monitor for events, such as the creation of processes (Sysmon Event 1), that involve auto-elevated CMSTP COM interfaces such as CMSTPLUA (3E5FC7F9-9A51-4367-9063-A120244FBEC7) and CMLUAUTIL (3E000D72-A845-4CD9-BD83-80C07C3B881F).

Answer (score 0):

`dllhost.exe` is simply a Microsoft-provided executable that can host any ["in-process" COM server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/com-clients-and-servers) (the code for which is in a DLL) via [a dedicated process (known as a "DLL surrogate") rather than as part of some other process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/dll-surrogates). Anybody can write these - creating and registering a COM server manually is moderately arcane but there's tools to make it pretty straightforward - and they can do anything that any other user-mode process running as the executing user could do. That certainly includes spawning child processes, either at a client's request or automatically in response to some event (which could just be "the server started" or could be something like "a particular named pipe closed").

It's possible that none of the Windows built-in COM servers ever spawn a child process in legitimate usage, though I'd be surprised (much less surprising if none of the ones that run by default ever do so, though; Windows has a LOT of obscure functionality implemented via COM but a typical home or even business user will never see most of it). It would be shocking if no legitimate third-party COM server ever spawned child processes, though. One could argue that spawning child processes is a weird thing for COM servers to do - normally either the client would spawn the process directly or the server would perform the requested operation in-process - but there is a tremendous amount of software in the world and some of it does basically any weird thing you can think of.